# How do I debug "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication"

Tags: ssh, logging, debug, x11-forwarding

I have a problem with  X forwarding through SSH. I've battled for ages, but no-one can seem to help.

I'm now taking a different tact. I would like to know how I would debug the errors?

What logs should I look in, what extra flags should I set (-v etc) and what should I look for?

Further Edit:

If I log into Putty into the server and try to `xeyes`, I get:

PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attemptedError: Can't open display: localhost:10.0

If I `xauth generate $DISPLAY` I get:

PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attemptedxauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0".

Comment: In [your question from the other day](http://superuser.com/questions/803766/x-over-ssh-and-xauth-not-working) you describe different symptoms. Are you still suffering from "Can't open display", or did you solve that? If you solved that, and one of the answers to that question was helpful, you should select it as an answer to reward the person who helped you.

Comment: Agreed, it's a different error now, I've closed that question.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/803585/x11-forwarding-failure-only-on-a-single-server/805060#805060) applies to your server.

Comment: Kenster, I didn't have either rc file on the server, so I created one and pasted the code. No difference.

Comment: In the PuTTY logs, this comes up after I try to run an x program (after SSH login).
2014-09-01 15:16:38 Received X11 connect request from 127.0.0.1:59566
2014-09-01 15:16:38 Opening X11 forward connection succeeded
2014-09-01 15:16:38 Nothing left to send, closing channel
2014-09-01 15:16:38 Forwarded X11 connection terminated

Comment: I think this is part of the same problem (Event before running an X program - DISPLAY=localhost:10.0):  "xauth generate $DISPLAY" gives "PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attemptedxauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0"."

Comment: This is getting ridiculous now. I completely removed OpenSSH, reinstalled and copied the configuration files in /etc/ssh to the server from a machine that forwarding works, but STILL I get the "PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted" error. I'm out of ideas now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working, it's working. haha.

FINALLY.

After finding out that it wasn't the system, by adding a test user (which x forwarding worked "out the box"), I thought I'd start copying the .bash* startup files across to virginise the "broken" user.

None of the files were different, so next I deleted the users .ssh directory. When I ssh'd in, it moaned about "Server refused our key", but I could log in using password. Once logged in, I could x forward perfectly.

I'll now try to setup the key again and see if I can get that working too. Then it'll be back to normal.

Comment: This worked for me too. I tried all other methods, but yeah apparently the problem lied in the keys.

Answer (score 14):

### My solution step by step:

#### 1) login with option -X remote host login root

```
$ ssh -X root@192.168.1.39
```

#### 2) check if existing .Xauthority file

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -al
[root@localhost ~]# vim .Xauthority
```

#### 3) copy .Xauthority file to directory the other user

```
[root@localhost ~]# cp .Xauthority /home/oracle/
cp: overwrite `/home/oracle/.Xauthority'? y
```

#### 4) set permissions for this file

```
[root@localhost ~]# chown oracle:oinstall .Xauthority
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 0600 .Xauthority
```

#### 5) login oracle user

```
[root@localhost ~]# su - oracle
```

#### 6) display setting in localhost:10.0

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
[oracle@localhost ~]$ ls -al
```

#### 7) lists xauth cookies existing

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ xauth list
localhost.localdomain/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  310f1b02c1080e73059391c193a1881b
localhost.localdomain/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  41843db100830a2aa352641ac47bb759
```

#### 8) adding

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ xauth add localhost.localdomain/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  41843db100830a2aa352641ac47bb75
```

#### 9) test

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ xclock
```

Hope they serve! @wcaraza

Comment: The part xauth add .... is  the trick

Comment: steps 3. and 4. did the trick for me

Comment: followed these directions but am still getting the same error. that error. (X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0).

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the SSH server has the `xauth` tool installed, and that your `~/.Xauthority` file is writable. (Non-existent is also okay, as long as `xauth` can create it.)

Check if xauth data is being updated:

```
server$ xauth list
```

Try manually adding dummy xauth data (again, on the SSH server), and see if `xauth` has any problems (e.g. being unable to create the lockfile or to modify the Xauthority file itself):

```
server$ xauth add localhost:123 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 d7e2e4a8c5aa4430bfcc2abb436940d2
```

If necessary, re-run under `strace`.

Run the SSH service in debug mode, by setting `LogLevel DEBUG2` in the server configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), or by starting sshd in debug mode directly:

```
server$ sshd -rddp 12234
```

(In this example, `12234` is the temporary SSH port that you need to connect to. Any free port will do.)

Comment: Thank you. Xauth on the server can write to the .Xauthority file. But what should it be setting? server = N40L, client = Lin001. Should the xauth list on N40L show an entry for localhost:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 {Lin001'sHexKey}?

Comment: @wkdmarty: Yes, your sshd will listen on a TCP port corresponding to display :10 (or :11, :12...), and this will show up as "localhost:10". As for the hex key, however, I don't really know if it's meant to use the _same_ key – I think ssh actually generates a new one, and acts as a proxy...

Comment: ok perfect, I can see that 0.0.0.0:6011 is listening. My DISPLAY variable states N40L:11.0, which I'm thinking is wrong, so I'll change that to DISPLAY=localhost:10.0. Nope, still erroring. I did notice on the SSH connection this line: debug2: x11_get_proto /usr/bin/xauth list :0.0 2>/dev/null wherever I've seen SSH connection logging, this line is different...showing a key generation, never :0.0.?

Comment: @wkdmarty: Normally sshd should set $DISPLAY to the correct value... and port 6011 does correspond to display 11, not 10, anyway.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say DISPLAY=localhost:11.0 as at that time I had 2 SSH sessions live. Still no joy though. Still no joy though. I'm about to give up as nothing I change works and there doesn't seem to be a definitive way of debugging the problem.

Comment: It seems that sshd is setting "machine_name":port. i.e. N40L:10.0 not localhost:port. I have checked the following files to make sure it's not in any login/startup files: ~/.bashrc ~/bash_profile /etc/.bashrc

Comment: Anyway, even if I manually set it correctly, I still get the wrong authentication error.

Comment: "My DISPLAY variable states N40L:11.0...so I'll change that". To be blunt, leave DISPLAY alone. If ssh sets up X11 forwarding, it will set DISPLAY to a value that will work. Overriding the value that ssh sets will just make the troubleshooting process more difficult.

Comment: OK, I've trawled over everything and DISPLAY sets itself to what I would consider correct: localhost:10.0. But I'm still getting "PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attemptedError: Can't open display: localhost:10.0 (on windows) and "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0" (on linux)

Answer (score 3):

One more thing that can cause this problem is the existence of a `~/.ssh/rc` file on the server--the machine you're connecting to.  Delete it (or rename it) to solve the problem.

Comment: Per `man sshd`, sshd runs `~/.ssh/rc` instead of `xauth`, @PimpJuiceIT.

Comment: Thank you! For more details, see: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch09_03.htm#ch09-33857. It should be possible to add the appropriate commands to start up xauth within the rc file, but I've not found it.

Comment: @KenJackson your answer pointed me to the snippet in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244821/270520), which made X11 work for me. I added:
`if read proto cookie && [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  echo "add unix:${DISPLAY#localhost:} $proto $cookie" | xauth -q -
fi` to my `~/.ssh/rc`.

Answer (score 1):

`rm ~/.Xauth*` and then reconnect.

This works for me. For more [details](https://www.starnet.com/xwin32kb/error-in-locking-authority-file/)

Answer (score 0):

One more wrinkle; sometimes X will run fine over SSH under your own individual user account, then throw "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused" the moment you use "sudo" or attempt any operation as 'root'.

The solution appears to be to run "xauth list" as your individual user, then "sudo xauth add" to add all the same the individual keys for the 'root' administrator.

ie:

```
$ xauth list
sophia/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  af8901b66c15a26f10d70e7e0199ea0b
sophia/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  9f9bf2b2cacc242d20d06d9523b2d304
sophia/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ec167527428b7726d7f36b514a6daec3
sophia/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  133573e87fc32af9634b04307df478fa
```

in a non-root user session which already has working X-over-ssh. Then "sudo xauth add" each of those keys, in this example:

```
$ sudo xauth add sophia/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  133573e87fc32af9634b04307df478fa
$ sudo xauth add sophia/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ec167527428b7726d7f36b514a6daec3
$ sudo xauth add sophia/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  9f9bf2b2cacc242d20d06d9523b2d304
$ sudo xauth add sophia/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  af8901b66c15a26f10d70e7e0199ea0b
```

Now you should be able to use "sudo" with any command that needs X window support:

```
$ sudo baobab
```

...or whatever. There are a few useful admin-type commands (ranging from 'gparted' to xenserver administration) which can make use of the graphics support if it's available - even over an ssh connection to a distant, remote datacentre.